# Propositional logic - help with simplification law for $p\land\neg q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

My first language is not English so excuse any grammar faults.
I have the following statement:
$\neg p\lor q\rightarrow p\land \neg q\iff \neg(p\rightarrow q)$

My question is, which law can I use for $p\land \neg q$? Is it the same as $p\land q\rightarrow p$? (I don't know what the law is called in English, in my paper its the law L5.

Otherwise I know how to get $\neg p\lor q$ to what I need I think.

I don't know how insert an equation in this site but I hope it's okay.

Thank you

Comment: For example, you can use De Morgan's law: $p \wedge ¬ q \equiv ¬ (¬p \vee ¬(¬q)) \equiv ¬ (¬p \vee q)$

Comment: That is not a well-formed formula.

Comment: Can I use that even if its not a ¬ in front of p too?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: I need to show that the right side and the left side are the same

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to logical equivalence laws, I like to break them down to all ands ($\land$) and ors($\lor$).

First let's simplify the right side of the equation. We have
$$
\begin{align}
(\lnot p \lor q) \to (p \land \lnot q) \\
\lnot(\lnot p \lor q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) && p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q \\
(p \land \lnot q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) && \text{Double Negation and DeMorgan's Law} \\
p \land \lnot q && \text{Idempotent Law}
\end{align}$$

Now, let's look at the right side. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\lnot(p\to q) \\
\lnot(\lnot p \lor q) && p \to q \equiv \lnot p \lor q \\
p \land \lnot q && \text{Double Negation and DeMorgan's Law}
\end{align}
$$

We see the that left side is the same as the right side. Thus, they're equivalent.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation! This is gonna help me in the future.